# What determines batch size in beam/dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline that uses the batch variant of `DoFn` (which the docs weren't very helpful for). It looks like this

```py
class MyFn(beam.DoFn):

    def process_batch(self, batch: List[MyType]) -> Iterator[List[MyType]]:
        # process batches
        results = []
        for foo in batch:
            # do work, add to results

        yield results
```

I've got some logging setup to shows me that my `process_batch` method is operating on `4096` items consistently. Does anyone know why its `4096`, or how to make it higher or lower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the BATCH SIZE is hardcoded to 4096 in the [batched DoFns](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/eed1713b5b8dc8e83ffb1fa43a4d0564083a23ce/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py#L262).
You can raise a [feature request](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/new/choose) in the apache beam community to make it configurable.